# How to prevent dependency from compiling duplicate dependency

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have an SDk in the form of an aar in my project's lib folder.  I am attempting to add it as a dependency in my project's build.gradle.

```
  dependencies {
      ...
      compile(name:'mySDK', ex:'aar')
      ...
  }
```

However, when I try to rebuild gradle, I get the following:

```
Error:(48, 0) No such property: ex for class: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dependencies.DefaultExternalModuleDependency_Decorated.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/http/impl/cookie/IgnoreSpecFactory.class
```

I unziped `mySDK` and confirmed that `httpclient-android-4.3.5.1.jar` is a library used in `mySDK` (this jar contains `org.apache.http`...).

I then updated my gradle to try and exclude this library.

```
  dependencies {
      ...
      compile(name:'mySDK', ex:'aar'){
        exclude(group: 'org.apache.http', module: 'httpclient-android-4.3.5.1')
      }
      ...
  }
```

I've also tried excluding:

```
exclude module: 'httpclient'
exclude(group: 'org.apache.http', module: 'httpclient-android')
exclude(group: 'org.apache.http', module: 'httpclient')
```

Unfortunately, I'm still receiving the same `java.util.zip.ZipException`.  Any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are bundling dependencies into your AAR?

Comment: "mySDK" is not MY SDK.  It's an SDK I'm attempting to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't do** it with an `aar file` and a `flat repo`.

You can do it only it you are using a maven dependency. In this case you have a pom file which describes the dependencies (with modules and group).

In an aar there isn't any pom file which describes that the jar file is a dependency called `httpclient-android-4.3.5.1` for example.

Usually the aar file doesn't contain the dependencies.
The best option is to have this aar in a maven repo in order to exclude dependencies.
Since it is not possible, an alternative could be to unzip the aar file, remove the jar dependency and repack the aar (it is a simple zip file).

Comment: So Is my only option to unzip the aar and try to dump everything in it into my project?

Comment: the alternative is to exclude the module from the other dependency if it is taken with maven.

Comment: Could you point me to some documentation about not being able to exclude from an aar file?

Comment: It is not so simple. Which other module has this dependency?

Comment: I'm not sure which module yet.  Trying to figure that out now.  It is in a separate progress.  I'm not excited about excluding httpclient there, and I'm not excited about exploding the aar.

Comment: The best option is to have the "mySdk" as an aar in a maven repo. Usually is not a good idea to bundle a dependency inside the aar file for this reason.

Comment: How difficult would it be for me to remove the jar from the aar file?  It is simple enough to unzip an aar and just delete the jar, but can I zip the aar back up somehow?

Comment: Yes you can try it.Remove the jar and then rezip the classes in the same way

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to when you say, "In the same way."  This SDK is not MY SDK.  My assumption is you use Android Studio to create an aar file.  I'm not sure if I can do that by opening the directory of an unzipped aar in AS.

Comment: The AAR is just a standard zip file so you can zip/unzip using the standard zip archive tools (which is what I think Gabriele meant by "the same way")

Comment: I've tried creating a separate module and adding `compile project(':mymodule-formy-sdk')` to my project's build.gradle.  However, gradle sync fails because the aar file (which exists in the libs folder of mymodule-formy-sdk) is not in the libs folder of my original project.  Why is it looking for it there?

Comment: It depends by the build.gradle. If you are adding the aar file in the dependency you have to pay attention to the relative path for the libs folder in the repository block.